# Highcharts: Bar with negative stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I copied highcharts' example ([Bar with negative stack](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack))
for 'Bar with negative stack' as is, and it does not show the same graph result. Actually, I can see only the positive axis columns and not the mirror ones.

Does anybody have a clue?

Thanks,

Gilad.

Comment: @PawełMichalski, do you have any idea? Sorry for bothering you

Comment: which version of highcharts do you use? and what browser?

Comment: I use chrome. Highcharts version: 4.2.6

Comment: Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), follow the guides and try to recreate the issue. The demo works for Highcharts 4.2.6 http://jsfiddle.net/7q1pnhLm/

Comment: I will do so. Thank you so much!